# HLS playback performance and stability on Chromecast

Tags: http-live-streaming, chromecast

I am having issues with HLS playback using the media player library at least since v0.3.0 which continue until the current version (v0.5.0). I know the player library is in beta so I am wondering if others see what I see.

Basically, the issue manifests itself in such a way that, after some time, Chromecast device becomes unresponsive. The debugger stops showing any output, closing it and attempting to access it again results in a timeout error. Sometimes, after some time, device just crashes to homescreen (no brainfreeze).

I tried looking at the profiles and timeline before this happens and I don't see any unusual spikes. I did notice some errors in the log (but they could be unrelated to this), saying something like:

```
An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

The only "unusual" thing I am doing is that I broadcast status on every video `timeupdate` event. This does not cause any such issues in normal playback though.

Comment: How long is "some time"? You can post a sample stream along with any logs and reproduction steps to our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list

Comment: Let's say order of magnitude is minutes. I still need to gather some data and try to isolate the repro steps more precisely. Until then I wanted to know if anyone experienced anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you already fixed that, I come with a workaround for people having the same problem.

I have a receiver streaming HLS (correctly encoded, using CORS headers and AES encryption). I noticed that sometimes the Chromecast goes crazy with huge segments (>25Mo) driving it to crash (almost) randomly when appending the latter segment.

Believing that I was probably asking too much of this small device, there are two solutions to lower the device load :

1. Disabling AES encryption (not always acceptable)
2. Reducing the segments quality

About solution 2, this works well :

```
window.host = new cast.player.api.Host({'mediaElement':mediaElement, 'url':url});
window.protocol = cast.player.api.CreateHlsStreamingProtocol( host );

window.host.getQualityLevel = function(streamIndex, qualityLevel){

    var lowestQuality = protocol.getStreamInfo()["bitrates"].length-1;
    var plusOneQuality = (qualityLevel == lowestQuality)?qualityLevel:qualityLevel+1;

    console.log( "original QualityLevel : " + qualityLevel, "returned QualityLevel", plusOneQuality );
    return plusOneQuality;
}
```

I'd love having some feedback about this. Does someone already had to use such a trick to prevent HLS HD streaming to crash the device ?